# How to find length of result array in Azure CLI via JMESPath?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, jmespath

I am trying to "explore" json results from an Azure CLI command using the `--query` switch (e.g. `az functionapp list --query <something>`), and to get started I'd like the length of the resulting array.

The Azure CLI help says nothing specific, and points to jmespath.org which does indeed show that a length function exists, however it seems to require an argument. I have no name for the argument, which is the root/outermost array returned by the list command.

It seems from jmespath.org that `length(something)` is what I want, but I don't know what to put in for the "something" part. What do I put here? Or am I going about this all wrong??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As we know `az functionapp list` returns a json where the root node is an array. In order to get the length of this array we can use the following syntax:

`az functionapp list --query "[] | length(@)"`

Comment: Wow! Looks like I have to get into this jmespath mindset somehow...

Comment: Great. I adapted to count the number of groups starting with a prefix and it worked perfectly: `az ad group list --filter "startswith(displayName,'EDL_P_EDU_')"  --query "[*].displayName | length(@)"`

Answer (score 1):

The following should also work:

```
az functionapp list --query "length([])"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for getting a slot count from the az functionapp deployment slot list:
--query "length([?defaultHostName=='slot host name to check'])"

Comment: Actually this worked in the Azure CLI tool, but when I used it in a GitHub action it did not work.  The accepted answer below did work however.

--query "[?defaultHostName=='slot host name to check'] | length(@)"